# Spring 3: A No action controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Could someone please point me to an example of XML configuration for Spring 3 MVC?
Specifically, I would like to know how to configure a controller that just returns a view... like

```
<bean id="urlFilenameViewController" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
```

in Spring 2.5

Comment: `UrlFilenameViewController` still works in Spring 3, why not just use that?

Comment: I guess I am not certain how the Spring 2.5 xml config would translate to Spring 3...

Comment: It doesn't need translating, it will just work as before.

Comment: And if I combine the XML conf with annotations, it won't clash?

Comment: By default, both should be able to work together. Try it and see. If it doesn't work, then modify your question to replace what you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would  tag help you?

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/some/path/" view-name="logicalViewName"/>
```

which just returns the view called logicalViewName for url /some/path/ 
[as per spring 3 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-view-controller)